# Связный список С++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Написал код создания, заполнения и вывода элементов связного списка:

```
class LinkList
{
    struct Node
    {
        int a;
        Node* next;
    };

    Node* head;

public:
    void AddElementAtFront(int x)
    {
        Node* current = new Node;
        current->a = x;
        current->next = head;
        head = current;
    }
    void print()
    {
        while (head != NULL)
        {
            cout << head->a << " --> ";
            head = head->next;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    LinkList obj;
    obj.AddElementAtFront(23);
    obj.AddElementAtFront(3);
    obj.print();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Работает, но Visual Studio кидает какое-то исключение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просмотрите, правильно ли был создан список, что посоветуете доработать\изменить\переделать?
Логика верна?

Comment: Посмотрел очень бегло - чего-то я не вижу инициализации head, хотя могу ошибиться

Comment: Есть ,после создания структуры

Comment: "Работает" - само собой работает... бесконечно причем. Хорошо что хоть Access Violation его тормозит. :D Наверное, все-таки ```while (current != NULL)```. Да и head обнулить надо при инициализации списка.

Comment: Ага вижу, я ошибся. Ну и Вам совершенно верно подсказывают, что его надо обнулить при инициализации списка.

Comment: Обнуляем , чтобы этот head встретить в конце и выйти из цикла, верно?

Comment: @Croessmah Вы бы оформляли в виде ответа - чтоб сразу было понятно:тут уже отвечено, можно не смотреть :)

Comment: @Harry так на вопрос не ответил же. "что посоветуете доработать\изменить\переделать?"

Comment: @Croessmah Ну, вы четко указали, что переделать :) Как по мне - для начала пусть ТС исправит эту ошибку, а там можно будет и дальше. Не делать же за него всю работу?

Comment: а для чего вообше нужен   Node* current в функции вывода?

Comment: если  уберу Node* current = head, значит все currentы в этой функции нужно заменить на head?
head-это самый первый или самый последний элемент?

Comment: исправил в коде, посмотрите

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Инициализируйте head

```
class LinkList
{
    struct Node
    {
        int a;
        Node* next;
    };

    Node* head = nullptr;
```

Comment: велком бэкк :-)

Answer (score -4):

Представляю программу с односвязным списком, позволяющую вставлять узлы в произвольное место, удалять произвольные узлы, двигаться по списку в произвольных направлениях. Мой подход опровергает мнение, что для таких операций необходим двусвязный список. Думаю, многие смогут найти ответы на свои вопросы.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node{
public:
    int item;       // значение
    Node *next;     // указатель на следующий узел
    Node(int i,Node *n=nullptr):item(i),next(n){}   // конструктор
};

// функция вставляет узел в произвольное место списка
// Если добавляет узел в конец, то получается FIFO
// Если в начало - то LIFO
void insNode(Node *node, Node *insnode, int n){
   cout << "Вставляем элемент после номера " << n << endl;
   if (n==0){   // если n == 0, то просто начинаем список
       node->item = insnode->item;
       node->next = nullptr;
       return;
   }
   int i = 1;
   while (i < n){
       ++i;
       node = node->next;   // последний узел в списке
   }
   insnode->next = node->next;  // insnode->next теперь указывает на nullptr
   node->next = insnode;
}

// удаляет узел с номером n
Node *delNode(Node *node, int n){
    Node *nodePrev = node;
    if(n==1){               // если удаляется первый узел
        if (node->next==nullptr){
            node = NULL;
            nodePrev = node;
            return node;
        }
        nodePrev = node;    // будем удалять
        node=node->next;    // прыгнули
        nodePrev->next = node->next;    // все, кроме адреса теперь новое
        nodePrev->item = node->item;
        node = nodePrev;    // адрес старый, значения перепрыгнули
        return node;
    }   // иначе
    int i = 1;
    while(i<n-1){
        node = node->next;
        ++i;
    }
    nodePrev = node;
    node = node->next;
    nodePrev->next = node->next;//указатель предыдущего узла перепрыгнул удаляемый узел
    node = nodePrev;//теперь в node данные предыдущего узла и указатель на следующий
    // за удаленным узлом, что и требовалось.
    return node;
}

// размер списка
int capacityList(Node *node){
    int i = 0;
    for(;node;i++)
        node = node->next;
    return i;
}

// получаем произвольный узел
int getNode(Node *node, int n){
    for(int i = 1;i<n;i++){
        node = node->next;
    }
    return node->item;
}

int main()
{
    Node *list = new Node(0);
    Node *prev = nullptr;
    Node *insnode;      // узел для вставки

    for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
        insnode = new Node(i);
        insNode(list,insnode,i);  // добавляем в конец списка
    }

    insnode = new Node(13);
    insNode(list,insnode,3);  // вставляем после третьего узла

    cout << "Узлов в списке:" << capacityList(list) << endl;

    // получить 4-й узел
    cout << "Узел № 4:\n";
    cout << getNode(list,4) << endl;

    // напечатать список с начала
    cout << "Список с начала:\n";
    for(int i = 1; i<=capacityList(list);i++)
        cout << getNode(list,i) << endl;

    // напечатать список с конца
    cout << "Список с конца:\n";
    for(int i = capacityList(list);i>0;i--)
        cout << getNode(list,i) << endl;

    // напечатать узлы с четными номерами
    cout << "Узлы с четными номерами:\n";
    for(int i=0;i<=capacityList(list);i+=2){
        cout << getNode(list,i) << endl;
    }

    // удалить четвертый узел
    Node *temp = nullptr;
    cout << "Удаляем узел 4:\n";
    temp = delNode(list,4);
    cout << "Список с начала:\n";
    for(int i = 1; i<=capacityList(list);i++)
        cout << getNode(list,i) << endl;

    cout << "Удаляем узел 1:\n";
    temp = delNode(list,1);
    cout << "Список с начала:\n";
    for(int i = 1; i<=capacityList(list);i++)
        cout << getNode(list,i) << endl;

    // удалить весь список
    cout << "Удаляем весь список\n";
    while(temp){
        temp = delNode(list,1);
    }
    list = NULL;

    // вывести длину списка
    cout << capacityList(list) << endl;

    delete list;
    delete insnode;
    return 0;
}
```